# Dowgrade from Win 8 to Win 7 on Sony Laptop with touchscreen

Tags: windows-7

I have downgraded and installed Windows 7 on a laptop which was bought with Win 8 pre installed.

In device manager, there are 2 unknown devices with the following identification:

- ACPI\GPIO0001 for one and,
- ACPI\SMB0002 for the second one.

The laptop is working fine, but I can't find the driver for these items. Look everywhere, including Sony website. I even bought Driver Finder to locate the drivers. But DriverFinder did not detect these devices and did not look for drivers.

Comment: The devices in question likely do not have a Windows 7 compatible device driver.

Comment: have you tried the Win8 drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this "Driver Finder" software's a scam.

From the Device Manager, under details, look up the Hardware IDs. That will be your first clue.

You should have little trouble installing windows 8 Drivers in Windows 7.